# Is it possible to view RDS data with Salesforce?

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-rds

So I am very new to Salesforce,  I would like to establish a connection between Salesforce and Amazon RDS. 
My goal is to GET a request from Amazon RDS with Salesforce. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "GET a request from Amazon RDS with Salesforce"? Are you saying that you want to run an SQL query against the Amazon RDS database from some code inside Salesforce? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I meant that I would like to read my RDS data from SalesForce and be able to inject it into SalesForce DB

Comment: You'll either need to find some Force.com code that can access an external database, or you'll need to run some sort of middleware that can talk to both Salesforce and the database. I suggest you begin by doing some research on how to access your desired database engine from Salesforce.